Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
I have an RCP application in eclipse. That works into eclipse, but when I export it, I have this stacktrace
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: feuvert [2]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.118.0.v20200807-0902"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui [20]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.120.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.120.0.v20200829-1411"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui.workbench [21]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.inject; version="1.0.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2024-05-21 10:18:24.883
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ui [20]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.120.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.120.0.v20200829-1411"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.workbench [21]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.inject; version="1.0.0"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1838)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1743)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

I've checked the plugins tab into run configurations and there are this bundles and also in tab "Contents" of my plugin.
I'm using java 1.8 and eclipse 4.17
Can someone help me? Thanks in advance
I've tried to add all the required plugins,

The root cause is Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.inject; version="1.0.0": a bundle/plugin is missing providing the  javax.inject package. Nowadays, RCP applications are build with Tycho. Also note, that Eclipse 4.17 is more than three years and 14 releases behind. Please upgrade.

If you are using maven Tycho couple with a p2 repository you need to add javax.inject in your p2 repository javax.inject in "plugins" directory and regenerate it.
Into the run configuration didi you add javax.inject ?
